# alueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' for svc technique

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

classification technique i am getting error:

> ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([1.1 , 1.12, 1.13, ..., 0.94, 1.39, 1.23]),) for MultinomialNB and ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous' for svc

i tried

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import utils

lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoded = lab_enc.fit_transform(ytrain)

print(utils.multiclass.type_of_target(ytrain))

print(utils.multiclass.type_of_target(ytrain.astype('int')))

print(utils.multiclass.type_of_target(encoded))
```

still i am getting error.

Comment: Please share some sample input and output for better understanding.

Comment: @mayank the data frame is hushed i can not put totally on here mnb=MultinomialNB()
mnb.fit(x_train,y_train)
predmnb=mnb.predict(x_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test,predmnb))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predmnb))
print(classification_report(y_test,predmnb)) this is i tried